# Doing unit conversion for UI values in QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, model-view-controller

I have subclassed QSqlTableModel and overridden data() and setData() to do unit conversion. That is, I want to multiply value by user-specified multiplier when going into db, and divide by the same multiplier when showing that field in the UI. However, for some reason setData() doesn't get called except for initially populating the fields.

Result: every time I click on a field in the UI, the conversion in data() gets done and the value divided, without it having been multiplied first in setData(). Clicking the field again and again, the field eventually reaches zero value.

What affects if setData() is called?

When I look at stack trace that reaches my data(), it seems QSqlTableModel::setData DOES get called each time, just not my function. I am submit()ing the changes every time setData is called so that ought not be the issue.

**Code in github repository now fixed to work as intended, as per the solution.** 
Full code: https://github.com/savolai/qsqltablemodel_conversion_example

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

// connect to db
QSqlDatabase db;
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "db");
db.setDatabaseName("db.sqlite");

if (!db.open()) {
    QMessageBox::critical(0, "Opening database failed",
        "Opening database failed. It really did.", QMessageBox::Close);
}

// connect model to db table table1
TableModel *model=new TableModel(this,db);
model->setTable("table1");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
model->select();

// add new record

QSqlRecord record;
QSqlField field0("radio", QVariant::Int);
field0.setValue(QVariant(QVariant::Int));

int fieldnumber=0;
record.insert(fieldnumber,field0);

int id=-1;
QSqlError error;

if(model->insertRecord(model->rowCount(),record)){
    if(model->submitAll()){
        id=record.value("id").toInt();
    }else{
        error=model->lastError();
        qDebug()<<error.text();

    }

}else{
    error=model->lastError();
    qDebug()<<error.text();
}

QDataWidgetMapper* mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
mapper->setModel(model);
mapper->toLast();


mapper->addMapping(ui->lineEdit,model->fieldIndex("text"));





}
```

tablemodel.cpp:

```
TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db)
    :    QSqlTableModel(parent,db)

{

}


bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, QVariant &value, int role){

    double dValue=value.toDouble();
    double baseValue=dValue*2;

    bool success=QSqlTableModel::setData(index,QVariant(baseValue),role);
    emit dataChanged(index,index);

    return success;

}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value=QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
    double dValue=value.toDouble();
    double userValue=dValue/2;
    return QVariant(userValue);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Sure! Made a simplified example that exhibits this behaviour. Divisions get done, multiplications not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your prototype for setData does not match the original.

you have

```
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, QVariant &value, int role)
```

when you should have

```
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
```

Comment: Thanks! #qt on freenode saves the day again!